# Only connect to WLAN_Y if WLAN_X is not available

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat

I have two wireless access points at home, one 2.4GHz (WLAN_Y) for the yard and one 5GHz (WLAN_X) for pretty much everything else.

The problem is that the 2.4GHz AP sits in the kitchen and every time I seem to walk by, my phone decides to use it's wireless, although WLAN_X would be faster.

I've tried to edit the `wpa_supplicant.conf` and alter `the priority` (set WLAN_X to 700 and WLAN_Y to 100). But that didn't change a thing.

How can I tell my phone only to connect to WLAN_Y (2.4GHz) if WLAN_X (5GHz) is **not** available?

`Android 4.4.4, Cyanogenmod 11 on a Samsung Galaxy S3`

Comment: I believe [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) can help here. You can use it to detect a Wi-Fi in vicinity and use your supplied amount of specific signal strength as part of the the trigger. The action can either be to connect or do nothing. Otherwise, if the Android deliberately switches back to WLAN_Y but WLAN_X is in vicinity then you can use Tasker to disconnect and reconnect to WLAN_X. Or, if you play with it more, you can come close to specifically what you asked here.

Comment: Several alternatives here: [Automatically connect to the strongest AP](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_automation#group_431) and [WiFi Priority](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_automation#group_999). Some ROMs ship with priority settings, but I assume those only do what you did manually. Some also have a priority setting for "2.4GHz/5GHz/auto" – which I would need here for the same AP offering both, but unfortunately that's just an either/or in my case (set to "5GHz" it would use 5GHz only, regardless what).

Comment: @Firelord: Tasker looks like it's overkill for this task.. I'd also prefer not to pay for such a, lets say, basic task
@Izzy: I'm currently testing `WiFi Connection Manager` from that list..

Comment: @Izzy, I've now tried multiple wifi prioritizer, but they don't seem to work in my case..

Comment: Sad to hear. But from your description, the first list might have better matches – unless "faster" does not equal "strongest signal" (i.e. "strongest signal" might be a router with lower speed).

Comment: Seems so.. the wifi for the yard is set for max. range but at low speed, thus the signal seems stronger for the phone, even if its a lot slower..