# How do I prevent connections?

Tags: wi-fi

When on my home WiFi network (or really any open network), when the WiFi drops or lags my phone automatically connects to my sister's phone (or that oepn network's 4G/5G alternative).

For example:

Our WiFi name is NetGear77. When it kicks me off NetGear77 due to instability or not loading fast enough, it forces me to connect to NetGear77-5G, which is my sister's phone.

My question is, how can I stop my phone from connecting to the other network when the WiFi lags or drops? It is weird when I can see my sister is searching up stupid crap like Twilight. I already have mobile data turned off, but I don't think it does anything.

Comment: I think this is related: [Only connect to WLAN\_Y if WLAN\_X is not available](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/126203)

Comment: What's 5G? I thought it was still in development in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your sister's WiFi network from your list of APs.

- Settings-> WiFi
- Long press the network name, which should be "NetGear77-5G"
- Select "Forget Network".

Also your sister probably should not be running a WiFi access point all the time. This will reduce her battery life, among other security issues.